# psql tool not working in pgAdmin 4 7.4 even after enabling psql in config.py file and only showing prompt blinking?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin 4 v7 on windows 11. I have enabled the config.py file of the configuration file for server and wanted to use psql tool from pgAdmin but when I click on psql tool after connecting to any databases,it only shows prompt blinking ?Can you please suggest how the psql tool can work from the pgAdmin in this case.

[psql tool only showing blinking cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj3dt.png)

Please help me to resolve this.

I have enabled the config.py file of the configuration file for server and wanted to use psql tool from pgAdmin but when I click on psql tool after connecting to any databases,it only shows prompt blinking